# How to add each indices in the array after multiplying them

Tags: java

I cannot retain the multiplied indices of the two arrays and add them, it always retains and multiplies the last indices.

For this example, I have values {1, 2, 3} and weights {0.1, 0.2, 0.7} and it should do something like this: 1*0.1 + 2*0.2 + 3*0.7 which will give me 2.6.

I have no problem doing this 1*0.1, 2*0.2 and 3*0.7, but it only retains the last indices and gives me 2.1 instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double[] values = {1, 2, 3};
    double[] weights = {0.1, 0.2, 0.7};
    System.out.println(weightedSum(values, weights));
}

public static double weightedSum(double[] values, double[] weights)
{
    double multiply = 0;    
    double sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){ 
        multiply = values[i]*weights[i];
    }
    return multiply;
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: You are missing to add the previous computed value in your for loop - `multiply = values[i]*weights[i];` should be `multiply += values[i]*weights[i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `multiply`, and not doing anything with `sum`. Instead, perform addition on your multiplicands and then add them to `sum`. Like,

```
public static double weightedSum(double[] values, double[] weights) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        sum += values[i] * weights[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution as long as two arrays are of same length is following :

```
    //Multiply two arrays of size 3 and output sum
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    double arr2[] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.7};
    final int LENGTH = 3;
    double result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        result += arr1[i]*arr2[i];
    }
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
    System.out.println("The result is " + formatter.format(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// functional style - The easiest solution as long as two arrays are of same length is following:

public static double weightedSum(double[] values, double[] weights) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, values.length)
                    .mapToDouble( i -> values[i] * weights[i])
                    .sum();
}
```